# ¿Porque da error?

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

quiero iniciar el servidor en laravel pero a la hora que pongo el comando me manda un error en el codigo

Adjunto codigo:

```
    <?php

    // autoload_real.php @generated by Composer

     class ComposerAutoloaderInitdbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304
    {
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
     */
    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        require __DIR__ . '/platform_check.php';

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitdbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(\dirname(\dirname(__FILE__)));
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitdbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitdbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            $includeFiles = Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitdbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304::$files;
        } else {
            $includeFiles = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_files.php';
        }
        foreach ($includeFiles as $fileIdentifier => $file) {
            composerRequiredbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304($fileIdentifier, $file);
        }

        return $loader;
    }
}

      function composerRequiredbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304($fileIdentifier, $file)
      {   
        if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
        require $file;

        $GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;
          }
    }
```

el editor me marca error en la linea 31 pero no entiendo porque no se si falte algo dentro del codigo estoy usando laravel y quiero implementar un captcha pero no me permite levantar el servidor para ver las modificaciones que e echo que puedo hacer ahi con ese error o que tengo que hacer para corregirlo

Adjunto imagen del error:

[image: ese error me da en la consola que puedo hacer ahi cabe recalcar que soy primeriso en laravel]

Comment: da error por que el archivo que busca no lo encuentra ...

Comment: y cual es la linea 31???

Comment: Indícanos donde está el error con exactitud.

Comment: el error lo da en esta linea $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitdbc6a4cfbb38d815161c757f8eb5f304::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

Comment: dice que la funcion no esta definida

Comment: has instalado los vendor? el error parece que viene de ahi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error es de un paquete de npm que no esta o no funciona, al parecer la instalación de laravel esta mala o le instalaste un paquete que trabaja buen con windows, podrias tratar de volver a tras si es que usas Git, sino aprende a usar git para evitar este tipo de fallas.
revisa que paquetes le instalaste en el autoload o el archivo package.json que es donde se agregan todas las dependencias.

**Nota**: hay paquetes que utilizan los enlaces simbólicos, que se rompen cuando haces un copy paste del proyecto.

Comment: listo muchas gracias instale las dependencias porque asi como clone el repo quito todos los errores